# Kubernetes pod terminated but container still occupying memory for a few minutes

Tags: kubernetes

I have several pods running an app and when redeploying (maxSurge=1,maxUnavailable=1) all pods are very quickly replaced but then I see a memory spike in the cluster showing double the memory used for 3-4 minutes (garbage collection delay???).

Is there a way to tell Kubernetes to clean up terminated pod's resources before creating another one?

Answer (score 0):

If you are a using a deployment object and you want to avoid rolling update, you need to use this in the spec section

```
spec:
  replicas: 3
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
```